# Text color changing (white/black) on background color changing from light to dark

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I create website using Nextjs. How I can make text color changing like the navbar at the bottom on this website - https://www.fuoripista.it/it/bike/
Will be good if there are some ready library for this on react.
I need to check video color from light to dark and change text upper video - white/black.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same video then you can't the color based on background. Because react cannot detect what's happening inside your videos.
If there are multiple videos or pages. You can pass a prop that tells your text component to change color when this page or video appears.